# Not getting proper output in IE8 while it's ok in google chrome?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

```html
<header>
    <H2>Logo Here</H2>
    <form>
        Search:
        <input type="text" name="search" class="search_bt" />
    </form>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Carrer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Loan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Education Loan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">All Loans</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</header>
```

This is my html code.
I am not getting proper output in IE8. So what's the issue is there?

```
this is my css
            body{
                margin:0 auto;
                width:1072px;
        }
        header,nav{
                 display:block
        }

        header{
                background:url(file:///C|/Users/Administrator/Desktop/banking/img/header_bg.jpg) repeat-x;

        }
        header h2 {
                float: left;
                margin: 0px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 48px;
                line-height: 48px;
                margin-top: 48px;
                color: #c40b51;
        }
        header form{
                float:right;
                margin-top:30px;
        }
        .search_bt{

                border-radius: 8px;
                height: 23px;
                background:url(file:///C|/Users/Administrator/Desktop/banking/img/search_bt.png) 100% 48% no-repeat;
                background-color: #f1edef;

        }
        nav{
                float:right;
                margin: 100px -200px;
                margin-bottom: 3px;

        }
        nav a{
                color:#666;
                text-decoration:none;
        }
        nav a:hover{

                background-color:#c40b51;
                color:white;
                border-radius:7px;
                padding:2px 6px;
                margin:0px -6px;
        }
        nav ul{
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
        }
        nav li{
                display:inline;
                list-style:none;
        }
        nav li:after{
                content:'|';
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
        }
        nav li:last-child:after{
                content:'';
                margin-left: -8px;
        }
```

this pseudo class nav li:last-child:after not working due to that i am getting divider of my last menu.
so how to fix it.

Comment: Any css to go with that html?

Answer (score 3):

You are using HTML5 elements (header and nav) in your markup. IE8 and lower doesn't support all html5 tags. Read up on the following link so you understand it, and add the following fs to your site and it should start to render:

https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks its working now. and another issue i use pseudo class in css for the divider its not working.

Comment: Post your css and what you're trying to do.

Comment: hello sir i am new to stackoverflow account will you tell how to add css code in my question?

Comment: Edit your question and paste it just like you did your HTML.

Comment: hello sir i have post the css.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 elements are not supported in IE version lower than IE9.

You can resolve this by including these lines in your `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```